# How do you make the numbers remain sequential for each group and even though there are rows that are affected by the merge?

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I have a problem when numbering each sub, because many numbers are not sequential when there is the same name in the merge

```
 // Set row per sub_department
  let firstRowBySubDepartment = {};
  let rowNumberBySubDepartment = {};
  let mergeStartIndex = -1;
  let mergeEndIndex = -1;
  let mergeColumn = "";
  let totalDaysAbsent = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
    const data = responseData[i];

    if (!firstRowBySubDepartment[data.sub_department]) {
      const subDepartmentRow = worksheet.addRow([data.sub_department]);
      firstRowBySubDepartment[data.sub_department] = subDepartmentRow.number;
      rowNumberBySubDepartment[data.sub_department] = 1;

      worksheet.mergeCells(
        `A${subDepartmentRow.number}:E${subDepartmentRow.number}`
      );
    }

    const subDepartment = data.sub_department;
    const no = rowNumberBySubDepartment[subDepartment];
    const dataRow = worksheet.addRow([
      no,
      data.name,
    ]);

    const row = worksheet.getRow(i + 9);
    const row2 = worksheet.getRow(i + 10);

    if (row.getCell("B").value === row2.getCell("B").value) {
      if (mergeStartIndex === -1) {
        mergeStartIndex = row.number;
        mergeColumn = row.number;
      }
      mergeEndIndex = row2.number;
      totalDaysAbsent += responseData[i].no_of_days_absent;

    } else {
      if (mergeStartIndex !== -1 && mergeEndIndex !== -1) {
        worksheet.mergeCells(`A${mergeColumn}:A${mergeEndIndex}`);
        worksheet.mergeCells(`B${mergeColumn}:B${mergeEndIndex}`);
      }

      mergeStartIndex = -1;
      mergeEndIndex = -1;
      mergeColumn = "";

      rowNumberBySubDepartment[subDepartment] += 1;
    }
  }

  // Merge last row
  if (mergeStartIndex !== -1 && mergeEndIndex !== -1) {
    worksheet.mergeCells(`${mergeColumn}:B${mergeEndIndex}`);
  }
```

I have tried giving the number when after the data has been merged, the output I expect is the number of each successive sub even when there is a row that has been merged. I use package exceljs

Comment: If you are using any kind of libraries (looks like you are using some spreadsheet library), please mention it in your post, and also tag it if the tag has a decent number of existence.